# RBAC - role recognition

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, roles, rbac

Is the following approach for the RBAC aspect correct? Can't a hacker change 'admin' to 'moderator'?

```
app.use("/users", requireRole.verifyRole('admin'), require("./routes/usersRoutes"));
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this differently?

Comment: If a hacker can change the source of your server and redeploy it you have a larger issue in play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'admin'` is hard-coded here, which is fine security-wise. In order to modify it an attacker will have to have access to modify the source code, which makes RBAC, or any security measure you may have a moot point anyway.